# How to sign a petition on a website with Tor (undisplayed button)

Tags: website

On this website (https://www.change.org/p/fran%C3%A7ois-hollande-monsieur-le-pr%C3%A9sident-la-france-doit-voter-%C3%A0-l-onu-l-interdiction-des-armes-nucl%C3%A9aires?tk=LANthiTZ4YhnYia83IpRD3C6fnMkdd6hLRkrojJFCpk&utm_medium=email&utm_source=signature_receipt&utm_campaign=new_signature)

a button titled "signer la pétition" (sign the petition) is not displayed with TOR.
How can I manage to get this button displayed and sign the petition with Tor?

The button matches with other browsers (IE for example)

Regards
Denis

Comment: The same issue to share this petition or to sponsor somebody

Comment: well, it won't make much sense to sign a petition with your name, city and mail-address from tor...!

Answer (score 1):

The site seems broken, accidentally. The way it's using Cloudflare breaks it for any IP that has some high "risk" score in their listing (I.E. any that would be prompted with a captcha before proceeding).

When you use the site you are first asked to fill in a Cloudflare captcha. Once it's successfully filled in Cloudflare assigns you some token in a cookie for the site that you can send with later requests to indicate that you've been previously validated by Cloudflare for access to the site.

However, this site serves at least some of it's content from a second sub-domain `assets.change.org`. It seem that the method of requesting causes any cookies to be stripped, as such when it's firing off the request our previously assigned Cloudflare cookie isn't present and this means that Cloudflare prompts us to fill in a new captcha instead of serving the content, this in turn means that some of the javascript that the site is trying to load isn't loaded, breaking functionality.

**Update**:

I was wrong, my own testing suggests this is *not* a firefox bug. Testing on a my own server, `<script async...>` tags are credentialed in cross-subdomain requests. This is a bug on their site, and likely not an intentional attempt to stop Tor users.

Comment: as far as I know, Cloudflare offers an option to it's customers to allow Tor traffic - and for a long time. So the site is intentionally blocking it for sure https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203306930-Does-CloudFlare-block-Tor-

Answer (score -1):

If it's not displayed - then the website is detecting that you're using Tor exit and refusing you to do the things you're trying to do. It **is** ridiculous - but even more odd things are happening so far, so it is not possible to do so: even if you will post a form successfully, it will be filtered out by the website - if it can detect Tor exit and refuses you in using it's functionality, it is able to prevent the form processing as well.